# How to share data between fragments and activities in android

Tags: java, android, oop, object

I am new to android.
Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to share data between activities and fragments using java interfaces. I have studied OOP but I am still stuck in interfaces and abstracts classes. I think if I implement a class on many activities, I will be able to share data like passing data from one activity and getting it from another.
Am I right about it? Please help me

Comment: Just a note on this one ali - my answer was before Jamies and covers the same therefore mine should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For between activities you can putExtra values such as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, newActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("someKey", someValue);
intent.putExtra(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

To get it inside your activity:

```
getIntent().getExtra("someKey");
```

For moving values between fragments i'd suggest using bundles:

```
//Where mainlayout is the top level id of your xml layout and R.id.viewProfile is the id of the action within your navigation xml.
       NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.mainlayout);
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("uid",snapshot.getKey());
                                    navController.navigate(R.id.viewProfile,bundle);
```

to retrieve this value within your fragment:

```
String game = getArguments().getString("game");
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: If you think this answer has helped then please use the tick button next to the answer and upvote it: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

use intents and them use the putExtra() and getExtra() to pass and recieve information, alternatively you can pass them as NavArgs() when using the jetpack navigation library.

[intents in java](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

[navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: Thank you. I used startActivityForResult already and it works but what if I need those results in another activity or fragment? Can you help me please

Comment: you can create a viewModel and share it between your activities or fragments to get access to the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Android has standards for setting and getting data in activities and fragments

To send data between activities

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("YOUR_INT", 1);
b.putString("YOUR_STRING", "Hello");
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

To send data to a fragment from an activity

```
// Declare a static method on your fragment 'New Instance'
public static MyFragment newInstance(int yourInt, String yourString) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("YOUR_INT_KEY", yourInt);
    args.putString("YOUR_STRING_KEY", yourString);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}

// Get the data inside your fragment
getArguments().getInt("YOUR_INT_KEY", 0); //Default value is zero if no int was found


// Instantiate your fragment wherever
MyFragment f = MyFragment.newInstance(1, "Hello");
```